# How to get the file object from request

Tags: javascript, python, django

I send file with javascript like this,

fetch png from server and send to the python

```
    fetch(fileUrl,{headers: headers})
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => new File([blob], "image.png"))
        .then(file => {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("metadata",JSON.stringify(metadata));
          formData.append("file",file);
            axios.post(
                ai_api,formData,{}
            ).then(function (response) {
                  console.log("sent success");
            }
```

then in django

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def jobs(request):
    metadata = request.POST.get("metadata")
    file = request.POST.get("file")
    print(metadata) # I can get the metadata here!!
    print(file) # None
```

why this file is None?

How can I get the file itself?

Comment: tried `request.FILES.get("file")`?

Answer (score 0):

is my first message
in my project
your fetch look like not bad。
i get file on nodeJs

```
 async uploadFile(ctx) {
    if (!ctx.request.files || !ctx.request.files.file) {
      ctx.status = 200;
      ctx.body = { message: "please chose files" };
      return;
    }

    // get file info
    const file = ctx.request.files.file;

    const { originalFilename, filepath } = file;

}
```

i hope can help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).